# How can i make any element first of Idictionary object in C# by key?

Tags: c#, sorting, idictionary

I have object type of IDictionary and i want to custom sort of object items e.g

```cs
 IDictionary<string, object> animalObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>()

animalObjects = {                                       
Monkey,SomeValue,
Cat,SomeValue,
Tiger,SomeValue,
Zebra,SomeValue 
}
```

Now i want to set **"Tiger"** as first element of object.

Comment: You can't; from the documentation: "The IDictionary<TKey,TValue> interface allows the contained keys and values to be enumerated, but it does not imply any particular sort order."

Comment: A `Dictionary` is inherently unordered.  You might want to try using a [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-sorteddictionary-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) and pass a custom comparer to its constructor, so you can put "Tiger" first. Since `SortedDictionary` implements `IDictionary`, you can fulfil your requirement with it.

Comment: What is the actual goal? Do you need to allow arbitrary order? If the number of items is fairly small it would be simple enough to do a `.OrderBy` whenever enumerating the collection, but you would need something to order items by.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary has no order. If you iterate over it, there is no guarantee that you will receive the entries in a certain order. If you need a certain order, you have to sort it by yourself. You can use LINQ for this:

```
foreach(var entry in animalObjects.OrderBy(x => x.Key != "Tiger"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " " + entry.Value);
}
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dwKtg4

Note that you will need to sort the dictionary every time you iterate it. If you want to iterate the dictionary very often and it has a lot of entries, this is not a smart solution. In that case, you should check whether a dictionary is the right data structure for your case. Maybe a `List<(string,object)>` is better in that case.